# Finding the "cheese" in an array maze

Tags: java, algorithm, maze

You're given an mxn array. The number 9 is the cheese, the number 0 is a wall and the number 1 is a path. You are the mouse and start in the top left corner a[0][0]. You need to find out whether there is a path to the cheese. This is the question I was given. I tried solving it a certain way and I was wondering if anyone could tell me whether it was correct or on the right path because I kind of thought of it spur of the moment and ran out of time on the test.

My thinking is that if you know you start at the top left corner, then you only need to move down and right if the array looks like this:

```
1 0 0 0 
1 1 0 0
0 1 1 9
0 0 0 0
```

So the top left corner is a 1, that means a path exists, so what I did was recurse on the top left corner provided by the adjacent cells to the right and left, creating 2 subarrays. so I called the isPath method on these two subarrays

```
0 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 9
0 0 0
```

and then on

```
1 1 0 0 
0 1 1 9
0 0 0 0
```

A basic version of the method looked like this:

```
isPath(int[][] matrix) {
    if(matrix[0][0] == 0)
        return 0;
    if(matrix[0][0] == 9)
        return 1; //found
    if(matrix[0][0] == 1) {
        subarray1 = copy starting from matrix[0][1]
        subarray2 = copy starting from matrix[1][0]
        isPath(subarray1)
        isPath(subarray2)
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to solve this? Or am I missing something

EDIT: No helper methods

Comment: Did you assume you can only travel **right & down** or was it part of the problem?

Comment: What happens if the maze goes down, then over, then back up?

Comment: My naive way to solve this would be: is there a path to "north", "east", "south", "west"? Test each one of them in a recursive call and pass the current position, so the recursive call won't go back to the way "I" came from. That way I can check each possible way, but it might also end up in a `StackOverflowError`, so it needs to more thoughts :P.

Comment: had 10 minutes and cannot use any helper methods

Comment: my worry also was that if the maze was too large checking every direction on every path would take up too much space but maybe that is negligible

Comment: Just check the next square, by going in an ordered way, for example, go only counterclockwise and mark the nodes you've visited by assigning their values 0. This will handle the StackOverflowError. Checking every node is time consuming but is necessary, because if you don't do that, you may not find a path at all! Think of it as walking in a dark cave with no idea of the exit. You have to try all turns. When something is necessary, do not think about the time it takes, because regardless of that, you have to do it if you need the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget array like this:

```
1 0 0 9 
1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1
```

your recursive function will not be finished in the previous example, please check the size of array to finish recursion.

Also your algorithm does not use up and right to find cheese

EDIT

you should handle the 4 directions, and don't repeat the square you visit before, I will add pseudo code here to explain the main idea of solution:

```
public class MAZE {

    static int x, y;
    static boolean result = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] matrix =new int[5][];// fill your array
        // fill x and y
        // x= cheese x value
        // y = cheese y value
        isPath(matrix, x, x);
        // print result


    }

    static void isPath(int[][] matrix, int i, int j) {
        if (i - 1 > -1 && matrix[i - 1][j] == 1) {
            // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i-1][j]
            // checkSPath(subarray1,i-1,j);
        }
        if (j - 1 > -1 &&  matrix[i][j - 1] == 1) {
            // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i][j-1]
            // checkLPath(subarray1,i,j-1);
        }

        if (i + 1 < x && matrix[i + 1][j] == 1) {
            // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i+1][j]
            // checkNPath(subarray1,i+1,j);
        }
        if (j + 1 < y &&  matrix[i][j + 1] == 1) {
            // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i][j+1]
            // checkRPath(subarray1,i,j+1);
        }
    }

    static void checkRPath(int[][] matrix, int i, int j) {
        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
            result = true;
        } else {
            if (i - 1 > -1 && matrix[i - 1][j] == 1) {
                // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i-1][j]
                // checkSPath(subarray1,i-1,j);
            }

            if (i + 1 < x && matrix[i + 1][j] == 1) {
                // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i+1][j]
                // checkNPath(subarray1,i+1,j);
            }
            if (j + 1 < y && matrix[i][j + 1] == 1) {
                // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i][j+1]
                // checkRPath(subarray1,i,j+1);
            }
        }
    }

    static void checkLPath(int[][] matrix, int i, int j) {

        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
            result = true;
        } else {
            if (i - 1 > -1 && matrix[i - 1][j] == 1) {
                // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i-1][j]
                // checkSPath(subarray1,i-1,j);
            }
            if (j - 1 > -1 && matrix[i][j - 1] == 1) {
                // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i][j-1]
                // checkLPath(subarray1,i,j-1);
            }

            if (i + 1 < x && matrix[i + 1][j] == 1) {
                // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i+1][j]
                // checkNPath(subarray1,i+1,j);
            }
        }
    }

    static void checkNPath(int[][] matrix, int i, int j) {
        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
            result = true;
        } else {
            if (j - 1 > -1 && matrix[i][j - 1] == 1) {
                // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i][j-1]
                // checkLPath(subarray1,i,j-1);
            }

            if (i + 1 < x && matrix[i + 1][j] == 1) {
                // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i+1][j]
                // checkNPath(subarray1,i+1,j);
            }
            if (j + 1 < y && matrix[i][j + 1] == 1) {
                // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i][j+1]
                // checkRPath(subarray1,i,j+1);
            }
        }

    }

    static void checkSPath(int[][] matrix, int i, int j) {
        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
            result = true;
        } else {
            if (i - 1 > -1 && matrix[i - 1][j] == 1) {
                // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i-1][j]
                // checkSPath(subarray1,i-1,j);
            }
            if (j - 1 > -1 && matrix[i][j - 1] == 1) {
                // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i][j-1]
                // checkLPath(subarray1);
            }

            if (j + 1 < y && matrix[i][j + 1] == 1) {
                // subarray1 = copy starting from [0][0] to matrix[i][j+1]
                // checkRPath(subarray1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can merge these 5 methods in one. here I am trying to explain the solution not writing optimized code.

Comment: i see that now. didn't consider the case in the time restraints. so the recursion should check all directions and then its fine? `isPath(up, down, left, right)` seems like it would take extremely long since it could cover every single node

Comment: you should handle the coming square, if you come from right, in next action don't go left, I will add code to help you

Comment: i get it. so just recursively call and you pass in the direction you came from as a variable